# Why i always get first item from array-variable?

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0, xls

$headerTitles has 4 values, but i always receive value with "1" index... Why?

```
`<xsl:variable name="tgroup" select="../../.."/>
    <xsl:variable name="colspecs" select="$tgroup/colspec"/>
    <xsl:variable name="headerTitles" select="$tgroup/thead/row/entry"/>

    <xsl:variable name="columnNumber">
      <xsl:call-template name="entry.getColspecAttributeValue">
        <xsl:with-param name="colspecs" select="$colspecs" />
        <xsl:with-param name="attrName">colNum</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="isLastEmpty">false</xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:attribute name="columnName">
      **<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[$columnNumber]"/>**
    </xsl:attribute>`
```

$headerTitles has 4 values, but i always receive value with "1" index... Why?

Comment: if there are 4 entries in the first header row $headerTitles will point to 4 entries.
In the logic that you show it is unclear which value $columnNumber will have. But from your question I suppose it will always be the column with the that value 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***-- edited in response to comments --***

> $headerTitles has 4 values, but i always receive value with "1" index... Why?

If the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[3]"/>
```

returns the string-value of the 3rd entry, but:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[$columnNumber]"/>
```

returns the value from the 1st entry, then the `$columnNumber` variable does not contain the number 3. Instead, it contains some value that when evaluated as a Boolean returns true for all entries (this could be even the *string* `"3"`).

In such situation, the `xsl:value-of` instruction in XSLT 1.0 will return the string-value of the first node in the selected node-set - see:
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#value-of
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions

Comment: So how i can get value by index 3 for example?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[3]"/>` should return the string-value of the 3rd entry. If you are getting a different result, edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, i get 3rd entry. But i need get index value from my varriable  <xsl:variable name="columnNumber">

Comment: I cannot help you without seeing how your variables are populated. If `<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[$columnNumber]"/>` is not returning the value from the 3rd entry, then `$columnNumber` does not contain the number 3.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1, with your variable declaration

```
<xsl:variable name="columnNumber">
  <xsl:call-template name="entry.getColspecAttributeValue">
    <xsl:with-param name="colspecs" select="$colspecs" />
    <xsl:with-param name="attrName">colNum</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="isLastEmpty">false</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

the value of the variable `columnNumber` is a result tree fragment containing whatever the `xsl:call-template` call returns, so it is a result tree fragment perhaps containing a text node with a number.

Inside of your predicate `<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[$columnNumber]"/>`, with `columnNumber` being a result tree fragment, that is not a positional predicate but just a boolean one always evaluating to true as any result tree fragment evaluates to true in a boolean context.

So you need to use `<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[number($columnNumber)]"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitles[position() = $columnNumber]"/>` to make sure you select based on the position.